# MYSQL getting error when using correct syntax and also logged in as a restricted anonymous user

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have searched all over the internet and asked several people at work how to resolve this issue but I'm about ready to give up... I installed mySQL on my laptop but I can't log in as a user.

```
Raymunds-MacBook-Pro:~ raymundsinlao$ /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2149
Server version: 5.6.13 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> -u root -p;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-u root -p' at line 1
mysql>
```

When I try to login it tells me that the syntax is wrong. I have tried a ton of different possible ways and it doesn't work.

My other problem is I am an anonymous user so I can't access any databases other than the information_schema and test.

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> use mysql;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'
mysql>
```

I have tried dozens of different things and have spent 8+ hours on this in the past 2 days. Please help me out!

Comment: Open a command prompt and type `mysql -uroot -p<yourpassword> and try use <db_name>

Answer (score 1):

You're separating `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql` and `-u root -p`, but these both belong on the command line, so it should look like this:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p
```

The fact that you're able to get in with just `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql` would mean that you're logging in as `root` already, just that that user has no password, and you'll definitely want to set a password on that account (once logged in):

```
use mysql;
update user set password=PASSWORD('NEWPASSWORD') where User='root';
```

Comment: Wow... I'm the ultimate noob... That worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, I think I did the same thing years ago my first time using MySQL :-).